# MP4 is downloading instead of playing

Tags: flash, google-chrome, video, mp4

MP4 files are sometimes downloaded, and other times they play in the browser.

What is the difference between these two links?

1) If you open this URL in Chrome, the video will download:

http://video.video-mall.com/video_mall/400241188377_video.mp4

2) If you open this URL on Chrome, the video will play in the browser:

http://www.simplethoughtproductions.com/wp-content/uploads/SimpleShorts/Morning_Mail/morning_mail.mp4

Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First link has `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` header, while the second one `Content-Type: video/mp4`.

Comment: How to convert dynamic media URL to octet stream

Comment: So is there a way to force chrome to play a file that has an octet-stream header?

Answer (score 4):

With [Serg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7391211/5263842) , I would also like to add about `Content-Disposition` header . If you set the Content-Disposition as `inline` , then your video/content will play within the browser and if you set Content-Disposition as `attachment` , then your browser will download it .

More info on this can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) .