# restify mp4 response body is downloading in browser instead of playing

Tags: google-chrome, mime-types, mp4, content-type, restify

I am using restify to serve an video url. I want this to play rather than download, and while I was confused about this as I am setting my `Content-Type: video/mp4`, I then saw my issue while testing in postman. The response header has `Content-Type: octect-stream`.

Why is restify not taking my header setting or what am I doing wrong? Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389378/mp4-is-downloading-instead-of-playing) but as I said, the change is not taking.

Here is my simple code:

```
    let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' };
    res.send(200, body, headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this to work by updating to res.redirect instead of res.send:

```
let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' };
res.redirect(302, body, next);
```