# XAMPP not Displaying MP4 file

Tags: html, xampp

I have this code in HTML:

```html
<a href="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">test</a>
```

However, it downloads it instead of playing it. When I try it on my desktop without XAMPP, it works. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks! (And yes, my browser does support mp4 files)

Comment: and the ``` was accidental in trying to format the code. oops! and I use the latest version of Chrome

Comment: Hey! That's a possible duplicate of several similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389378/mp4-is-downloading-instead-of-playing You should better try to search for an existing question with answers instead of creating duplicates. Here's also a short guide on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this instead of anchor tag

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You have to embed your video with html5 `<video>` tag like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

read more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)